# React typescript passing value from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to pass a value from the child component subject-section to the parent section. However, the TypeScript interface is not happy about it. **I get an error onUrlUpdate does not exist on the interface.**

So what am I suppose to do? Add `onUrlUpdate?: string` to interface. But that could pollute my interface. What if I have to pass 5 functions to the parent?

Interface

```
export interface CourseSectionInterface {
    id?: string;
    title: string;
    lessons: LessonsInterface[],
}
```

Parent

```
<React.Fragment key={section.id}>
 <SubjectSections
  title={section.title}
  lessons={section.lessons}
  onUrlUpdate={changeVideo}
  />
</React.Fragment>
```

Child

```
 const SubjectSections: React.FC<CourseSectionInterface> = ({title, lessons, onUrlUpdate}) => {
  const passUrl = (url: string) => {
    onUrlUpdate(url);
  }

  return (
   <h2 onClick={() => passUrl('url')}></h2>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to modify that interface, why not just create a new interface which contains a `CourseSectionInterface` + a function, and use that instead.

Comment: Maybe, but that would be against a DRY principle. I think just updating the interface would be simpler.

Comment: It would only go against DRY if you had the same properties included on both interfaces, if you have an interface containing another interface, there is no repetition of the types. `interface A { a: string }; interface B { a: A, b: () => void }`

Comment: I guess you right.